# asp.net 4.0 - routing root pages and validator controls issue

Tags: asp.net-4.0, asp.net-routing

I am simplifying my question:

When I route all my .aspx pages on my web app root the following way in global.asax:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("RootPages", "{file}", "~/{file}.aspx");
```

it all works fine as far as the routing goes, but none of my requiredfieldvalidators are firing anymore, it just does a full postback without validating my fields. When I remove the above code from the validators work again.

Can someone please verify if they are getting the same problem, or am I doing something wrong?

*When you test this please make sure you do a hard refresh (CTRL-F5) on your browser screen after you add or remove the code. BTW I have tested this on IE, FireFox and Chrome, they all behave the same way.

Thank you,

Comment: Can someone please try the above and see if you are getting the same results?

Why does the requiredfieldvalidator stops working when I have the above piece of code in my global.asax?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The answer it in this piece of code that needs to be added to the global.aspx:

```
routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

please refer to this article for more details:

[article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx)

I hope this may help someone, I'd spent over too days scratching my head over this.